# Custom horizontal navigation bar for Beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, navigation

I would like to create a beamer theme for my presentations. I like to show in the presentations a horizontal navigation bar in the header to give a reference of the progress of the presentation.

In my PowerPoint presentations I usually add a shape similar to tikz's signal for each section, shading everyone except for the current section or changing fill colour as shown in the figure.

[image: Deasired header result]

After checking how the `\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal` and `\dohead` beamer macros are implemented, I am still not able to identify where each section name and hyperlink is included in the header. It is the first time I dig into Plain TeX macros, so I don't fully understand the default definitions. Adding a tikz node to my custom `\myinsertsectionnavigationhorizontal` definition allows me to include a common shape for the whole header:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\usetheme{default}

\makeatletter
\def\myinsertsectionnavigationhorizontal#1#2#3{%
  \hbox to #1{{%
     \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{}%
     #2\hskip.3cm%
     \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
     \setbox\beamer@sectionbox=\hbox{}%
     \ht\beamer@sectionbox=1.875ex%
     \dp\beamer@sectionbox=0.75ex%
     \tikz\node[draw=myblue,fill=myblue,shape=signal,signal to=east,very thick,text=white]%
         {\hskip-1.875ex plus-1fill\dohead\box\beamer@sectionbox\hfil\hskip.3cm};%
     #3}}}
\makeatother

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,112,188}
\setbeamercolor*{section in head/foot}{fg=white}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=1.1cm]{frametitle} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox[fill=white](0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,1.2);
\node[anchor=west, myblue,font=\large] at (0.5cm,0.61cm){\insertframetitle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{beamercolorbox}
}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip5pt\myinsertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{\hspace{0.5cm}}{\hspace{0.5cm}}\vskip5pt
\end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}

\section[Introduction]{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
Text here.
\end{frame}

\section[Prev. Work]{Previous Work}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Previous Work Overview}
Text here.
\end{frame}

\section[Design]{Design Procedure}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Design Overview}
Text
\end{frame}

\section[Results]{Experiment Results}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
Example text.
\end{frame}

\section[Conclusion]{Final Conclusions}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Conclusion}
Text.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Resulting Header Style]

How would it be possible to specify an individual shape for each section name, and if possible a different one for the current section?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I have just added the MWE, and sorry for the newbie issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4.8ex,dp=0.125ex]{palette}%
        \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{%
    \if\insertsectionheadnumber1
        \tikz\node[draw=blue,fill=blue,shape=signal,very thick,text=white]{\insertsectionhead\hskip.3cm};
    \else
        \tikz\node[draw=blue,fill=blue,shape=signal,signal from=west, signal to=east,very thick,text=white]     {\insertsectionhead\hskip.3cm};
  \fi
}

\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{%
    \if\insertsectionheadnumber1
        \tikz\node[draw=blue,fill=white,shape=signal,very thick,text=blue]{\insertsectionhead\hskip.3cm};
    \else
        \tikz\node[draw=blue,fill=white,shape=signal,signal from=west, signal to=east,very thick,text=blue]     {\insertsectionhead\hskip.3cm};
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{The questions}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{A test frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Another questions}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Another test frame}Test
%\textcolor‎{‎letterfoot‎}{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}‎
\end{frame}

\section{section2}
\subsection{The questions}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{A test frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Another questions}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Another test frame}Test
%\textcolor‎{‎letterfoot‎}{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}‎
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh! I can't imagine the solution could be that simple, I was definately heading towards the wrong direction. Thanks for the help!